# Doesn't matter what is correct or what correct is?

Tags: word-order

When we're asking a question we use a reversed order of words:

> Where **is** *he*?

When we're stating something we're using the normal order:

> I don't know where *he* **is**.

But what about one?

> It doesn't matter what **is** *correct* - if enough people make that mistake it stops being a mistake anymore.

Above I see the reversed order. Or maybe it just appears that way? At the moment of writing this I'm realizing that maybe it's not the case here since it's a verb-adjective pair instead of a verb-noun pair?

But anyway, maybe the alternative is correct then?

> It doesn't matter what *correct* **is** - if enough people make that mistake it stops being a mistake anymore.

Comment: In your context, *It doesn't matter what correct is* means it's irrelevant ***how we define the term "correct"***, whereas *It doesn't matter what is correct* means it's irrelevant ***which terms are defined as "correct"***. They're both valid, but they convey different emphases.

Comment: Thank you for finding a way to succinctly sum up what I've spent the past hour contemplating how to explain, Fumble. :P

Comment: @FumbleFingers So does one use the reversed order **only** for the verb-noun pairs?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken NPS, this is an example of copular inversion, which relates specifically to "be" being the finite verb (of which "is" is the third-person singular present form)

Comment: @John: There's some exploration of copular inversion [here](https://literalminded.wordpress.com/category/syntax/inversion/), pointing out that *Where never is heard a discouraging word* is in that general area, but not quite an example. I'm not sure, but I think copular inversion might be better illustrated with *Who are you?* (which is sometimes "inverted" to *[And] you are who?*).

Comment: NPS: I don't understand what you're asking. There are lots of contexts where a non-standard *meaning* can be conveyed by a non-standard *word order*. Your "correct" example is one of them, where "correct" can either be a normal adjective *(What is correct? **This** is correct)*, or effectively a fairly unusual "noun" usage *(What does [the word] "correct" mean?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative most certainly isn't correct, and your realization about comparing a verb-adjective to a verb-noun pair is correct.

In the second example, the pair ought to be highlighted as "It doesn't matter *what* **is** correct", and the word order is preserved.